# Is it possible to download the VS2008 "Test Project" template?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates, test-project

For some reason, my visual studio 2008 installation doesn't have the "Create Test Project" template installed. I'm assuming I should be able to download it from somewhere on MSDN, but I cannot find it anywhere (Guess my Google-Fu is weak)

Does anyone know where I can get the template to install it?

Thanks

EDIT: I've managed to get my hands on the project templates from another dev machine, but now devenv /installvstemplates still doesn't seem to install the template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look a this [article](http://blogs.telerik.com/KevinBabcock/Posts/08-07-20/Visual_Studio_Tip_Creating_and_Consuming_an_Item_Template.aspx) about consuming project templates to see if it brings some light to the subject of installing the copied template.

You haven't said which client editions are installed on your machine. Test projects are available in Team Edition for Software Testers and in Team Suite.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that all Team System specific editions of VS had MSTest templates installed by default

Comment: Oh why don't Microsoft produce articles like this for their own software.  Took me a while to figure how to do my first template.  +1 for the find.